# org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: ERROR: null value in column "sched_time" violates not-null constraint,

Tags: java, postgresql, quartz-scheduler

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;

public class QuartzTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("Hello Job").build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(
                            /*CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")*/
                            simpleSchedule().
                                    withIntervalInSeconds(15).
                                    repeatForever()
                    )
                    .build();
            // and start it off
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            // scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: ERROR: null value in column "sched_time" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (StepScheduler, NON_CLUSTERED1466000944643, dummyTriggerName, group1, NON_CLUSTERED, 1466015299949, null, 5, ACQUIRED, null, null, f, f). [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "sched_time" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (DecisionIQStepScheduler, NON_CLUSTERED1466000944643, dummyTriggerName, group1, NON_CLUSTERED, 1466015299949, null, 5, ACQUIRED, null, null, f, f).]

Can some one help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to a version mismatch between quartz-scheduler.jar and SQL schema file.